How to replace maven profile properties from command line args
I have a settings.xml file that inject properties into pom.xml. I want to replace the profile properties with command line args.
settings.xml
    <profile>
        <id>ch1</id>
        <properties>
            <business.group.id>${ch.business.group.id}</business.group.id>
            <connected.app.client.id>${ch.connected.app.client.id}</connected.app.client.id>
            <connected.app.client.secret>${ch.connected.app.client.secret}</connected.app.client.secret>
        </properties>
    </profile>

My command line:
mvn deploy -DmuleDeploy -P=ch1 '-Dch.business.group.id=any_value
' '-Dch.connected.app.client.id=any_value' '-Dch.connected.app.client.secret=any_value'

Yes you can do something like this.  It's not clear what you're saying the problem is?

Why do you have properties in your settings.xml? Why not put them into your pom.xml ?
